# change atexit behavior based on program status

Tags: c, atexit

I am trying register one function with `atexit ()` that will print different messages based off of the current status of the program. I know that when you register the function with `atexit` you cannot pass an argument.

So, how can you pass the program status, say an integer, and make that function print different statements?

I know that I can register multiple functions, but I have to only use one.

Comment: Hold your nose and use a global variable?

Comment: I should have thought of that...thanks!

Comment: Actually, the man page for `atexit()` mentioned `on_exit()`  Look at that function, it takes arguments.

Comment: That sounds like a better option. Thanks again

Comment: If on_exit (my docs call it _onexit) is not an option you could also consider using libffi to create a closure. Basically creates a small function at run-time that can associate parameters besides those provided by the call.

Comment: I have to use atexit for this program. It seems that the only way to do this is with global variables. Thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a global variable.  That can be read by your function registered with `atexit`.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `atexit`, make use of the `on_exit` function which takes the status passed into `exit()` as one argument, and a `void *` that you can pass in.

> int on_exit(void (*function)(int , void *), void *arg);
>
> The  on_exit() function registers the given function to be called at
>   normal process termination, whether via exit(3) or via return from the
>   program's main().  The function is passed the status argument given to
>   the last call
>          to exit(3) and the arg argument from on_exit().
>
> The same function may be registered multiple times: it is called once for each registration.
>          When a child process is created via fork(2), it inherits copies of its parent's registrations.  Upon a successful call to one of the
>   exec(3) functions, all registrations are removed.

Comment: I'd certainly suggest `on_exit` if it's available. The only, if at all, problem is its a glibc extension and thus may not be available everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different idea. Instead of using a global variable or different atexit handlers, you could use a simplr exit wrapper that prints
the desired message and then calls `exit`.

```
void my_exit(int rc)
{
   /* Assuming you have enum constants ERR_1, etc,
    * with expected error codes and 0 isn't an error condition. */

   switch(rc) {
   case ERR_1:
       /* print message */
       break;
   case ERR_2:
       /* print message */
       break;
   ...
   }

   exit(rc);
}
```

Instead of ERR_1, etc, you could directly use integer constants or use if-else statements. Now you can pass the exit code to `my_exit` and use it wherever you'd use `exit()`. You would call it at the end of `main()` too with `my_exit(0)`.